# How can I perform a ZERO-COPY assignment from an array in C#

Tags: arrays

OK, so I am desperately looking into doing some Zero Copy assignments in C#. The problem at hand is I have a byte array, say array1. I need to point to a specific location with in that array, now the tricky part is to actually not copy the bytes from that specific location onwards till the end, rather somehow I must have those bytes accessible. To make this small portion of data accessible, I must have it in another byte array,say array2. I cant use Array.Copy() as it will create a copy of data, now I have to use unsafe/fixed constructs and point to that specific portion of data. In simple words, without copying make already existing data accessible via another array or something. I seem to lack the know how of that magic!

```
byte[] array1 ---> contains data say 10 elements
byte[] array2 ---> This must have the data from array1 from element say, 2-8 without  
copying the data from array1
```

Any help is highly appreciated,

Thanks
(P.S. Is it even possible?)

OK So I did some benchmarking and finally got through some hurdles. thanks to [dtb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76217/dtb) suggestion on ArraySegment, it solved most of my problems.

The results are as follows (posting as per my requirement)

```
Construct     Size    Elements accessed      Iterations       Time
_____________________________________________________________________

Array.Copy     1000        100                 1000000       53.7 ms
ArraySegment   1000        100                 1000000       23.04 ms
```

Using a core2 duo - 2.53 Ghz, 2GB Ram, running under .NET 3.5 (C#,VS2008)

And I am more a happy developer than I was a few minutes ago. Cheers  to Dtb!

Code is below. Will appreciate any flaws pointed out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ArrayCopyArraySementProfiling
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        public static TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan();
        public static double totalTime = 0.0;
        public static int iterations = 1000000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size = 1000;
            int startIndex = 0;
            int endIndex = 99;
            byte[] array1 = new byte[size];
            byte[] array2 = new byte[endIndex - startIndex + 1];

            for (int index = startIndex; index < size ; index++)
            {
                array1[index] = (byte)index;
            }

            ArraySegment<byte> arraySeg;
            for (int index = 0; index < iterations; index++)
            {
                stopWatch.Start();
                arraySeg = new ArraySegment<byte>(array1, startIndex, endIndex);
                stopWatch.Stop();
                totalTime += stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("ArraySegment:{0:F6}", totalTime / iterations);
            stopWatch.Reset();
            totalTime = 0.0;

            for (int index = 0; index < iterations; index++)
            {
                stopWatch.Start();
                Array.Copy(array1, startIndex, array2, 0, endIndex);
                stopWatch.Stop();
                totalTime += stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Array.Copy:{0:F6}", totalTime / iterations);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET an array cannot point into another array. What you can do, is to pass an offset and length along `array1`, so the recipient reads the array from that offset for the given length instead of starting at `0` for `array.Length`.

Have a look at the [ArraySegment<T> Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx).

Comment: Well, it looks promising. Almost what I needed. Still the "new" keyword literally kills me. Its slows things down which is actually what I don't want. Nevertheless, I will have to do some profiling agains Array.Copy(). Thanks anyway, cheers!

Comment: If it literally kills you, how are you still typing? Zombie!

Comment: @Jonathan, well what can I say? I miss C for its speed! And still alive because of C!!!